# Is there a way to access request object in django inline formset clean method?

Tags: django, django-forms

Got this admin class with inline and form classes:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    inlines = [InvoiceLineInline, ]
    form = InvoiceForm
    ....

class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean():
        ....

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        exclude = []


class InvoiceLineInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = InvoiceLine
    formset = InvoiceLineInlineFormset
    extra = 1


class InvoiceLineInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(InvoiceLineInlineFormset, self).clean()

        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue

            data = form.cleaned_data
            try:
                if data:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    continue
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            if Decimal(data.get('quantity', 0)) <= 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Amount should be greater than 0.")
            ******************************************************
            _stock_code = data.get('stock_code', None)
            if not len(fetch_stocks_from_connector(request, stock_code=_stock_code)):
                raise forms.ValidationError("{} Stock code does not exist at connector.".format(_stock_code))
            ******************************************************    
        if count < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Need one line at least.')
```

I need to do extra validation with an external method for the `_stock_code` value in each *inlineform* within *InvoiceLineInlineFormset.clean* as displayed above between the starred lines. But external method needs request object as *argument* to run properly.

Is it possible to pass request object to clean method?

Comment: may be `kwargs['instance']` is what u are looking for? In custom admin form I use it.

Answer (score 7):

The question is old but I'll share the solution that worked for me
ModelAdmin has a get_formset method. You can extend it like this

```
class YourAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = YourModel
    formset = YourInlineFormSet

    def get_formset(self,request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        formset = super(YourAdminInline,self).get_formset(request,obj,**kwargs)
        formset.request = request
        return formset
```

In your formset you can access the request object using `self.request`. For example in the clean method

```
class YourInlineFormset(forms.BaseInlineFormset):
    def clean(self):
        ...
        request = self.request
```

Answer (score 1):

Base `ModelAdmin` class has `_create_formsets()` method which, well, generates formsets:

```python
def _create_formsets(self, request, obj, change):
    "Helper function to generate formsets for add/change_view."
    formsets = []
    inline_instances = []
    prefixes = {}
    get_formsets_args = [request]
    if change:
        get_formsets_args.append(obj)
    for FormSet, inline in self.get_formsets_with_inlines(*get_formsets_args):
        prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
        prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
        if prefixes[prefix] != 1 or not prefix:
            prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
        formset_params = {
            'instance': obj,
            'prefix': prefix,
            'queryset': inline.get_queryset(request),
        }
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset_params.update({
                'data': request.POST,
                'files': request.FILES,
                'save_as_new': '_saveasnew' in request.POST
            })
        formsets.append(FormSet(**formset_params))
        inline_instances.append(inline)
    return formsets, inline_instances
```

As you can see by extending `formset_params` with method's `request` argument in your `ModelAdmin` class you can then save extra kwarg with request in formset's class `__init__()` and later use it in `clean()` method via `self.request`.

**Note that this is not the cleanest solution** as method implementation does not allow to extend only kwargs easily so entire method needs to be moved to your `ModelAdmin` and with any Django's update of this part of code you will need to update your method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same question (how to get request.user stuff from inline methods) and I got this answer which worked for me:
[Django: access to user info from admin.py for methods with no request object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268099/django-access-to-user-info-from-admin-py-for-methods-with-no-request-object)