# Django: access to user info from admin.py for methods with no request object?

Tags: django, request, admin, subclass

Django 1.11.

In `admin.py` I have:

```
class AuditAdmin(DeactivateMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
   """all the superclass stuff"""
```

from which I subclass my model's stuff with various custom methods:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(AuditAdmin):
    list_display = ["filed1", "filed2", "field3"] 

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser: 
            #do something extra

    def inline_add_somemodelattribute1(self, my_object):
        #how to access user if I don't have request ?
```

So inside `inline_add_somemodelattribute1` method I need to make decision based on the user but that method does not take `request` as an argument. How do I get my `user` data in this case? I did not find anything relevant  in `self` or `my_object`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way of access current request is using [crequest](https://pypi.org/project/django-crequest/). You can use it like this:

```
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware

class SomeModelAdmin(...):
     ...

     def inline_add_somemodelattribute1(self, my_object):
          crequest = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
          # your logics here for example: if crequest.user.pk == 1:
```

Comment: Sounds like a solution, but in `inline_add_somemodelattribute1`  after  `crequest = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()` crequest is aways `None`. It is ok in `get_queryset` however.

Comment: I mean the `request` passed to  `get_queryset` is OK.

Comment: Started to work when I added `CrequestMiddleware.set_request(request)` to `def get_queryset`. But this fix seems to be prety random to me. And I don't see it as required in the documentation.

Comment: @SwissNavy have you added `crequest.middleware.CrequestMiddleware` in middleware and `crequest` in `INSTALLED_APP`?

Comment: Yes, I added those two settings. Still had to add `CrequestMiddleware.set_request(request)` to `def get_queryset` to be able to get_request with actual request object returned instead of None.

Comment: It says to use `set_request` in unknown situation: https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-crequest#id5 in documentation

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks. Do you know if that can be set globally (instead of inside a specific method in a specific class like I do that)?

Comment: BTW, sorry can't upvote, do not have enough "reputation" for that

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped :) . And I am not sure about how to set it globally. I have used this library long time ago, and for that I did not need to set up anything, and I used this library is models's save method. As there is no other choice, maybe you can use it using `set_request` in queryset method for now.

Comment: Accepted and went with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider setting some values that you may require in your custom methods related to request user in `changelist_view` method as :

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # setting is_superuser attribute to be used in custom methods.
    setattr(self, 'is_superuser', request.user.is_superuser)

    return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Comment: I see. Yes, that's another way to make stuff accessible.